# How to find a coefficient in combination?

Tags: combinatorics

Given statement

$ \prod_{i=0}^n(\sum_{j=0}^n (a_{i,j}*x_{j})) $ where parameter $a_{i,j}\in\Bbb \{0,1\} $

How to show that coefficient for the combination $x_0*x_1*x_2*...x_n$ after expansion is odd or even ?

I tried to use inclusion–exclusion principle but for a large $n$ it requires to iterate over all combinations to find a solution.

Also tried to build a recurrence relation and then generating function for it but with no luck.

Would it be possible to find a formula in closed form for this sequence ?

Comment: I would start by taking a relatively small $n$, for example $n=1$ or $n=2$ and playing around with the expression in order to get a feel of what is going on.

Comment: The fully expanded form is $$\sum_{0\le j_0,\ldots,j_n\le n}a_{0,j_0}\cdots a_{n,j_n}\cdot x_{j_0}\cdots x_{j_n}.$$

Comment: Modulo $2$, the coefficient of $x_0\dots x_n$ is equivalent to the determinant of the matrix $A=(a_{i, j})_{i, j=0}^n$. So, just use your favorite algorithm to compute the determinant, using arithmetic $\pmod 2$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, thanks for your help! Is it really so easy ? Could you please explain me why it will work ? Not sure I understand your idea.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, yes but wait. Will I be able to compute determinant for a reasonable time if n is large, for example 100000 ?

Comment: Computing $\det A$ takes $O(n^3)$ time, so this is not feasible past $n=1000$. Do you have any reason to expect a reasonable algorithm exists for $n\approx 100000$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest, As I understand, polynomial expansion takes $O(n^n)$ in the worst case and manually iterating over all combinations will take $O(n!)$ so $O(n^3)$ is much better. To solve this problem my idea was to find a formula in the closed form using generating function and calculate coefficient instantly $O(1)$ similarly to how coefficient is calculated in binomial theorem. I was wondering if it is possible to do because my experience in recurrence relations and generating functions is poor to derive this formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By expanding out that product, you can see that the coefficient of $x_0\cdots x_n$ is equal to the permanent of the matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j=0}^n$. The permanent is like the determinant of a matrix, but without the negative signs:
$$
\text{coefficient of $x_0\cdots x_n$}=\operatorname{per}A=\sum_{\pi} a_{0,\pi(0)}\cdot a_{1,\pi(1)}\cdots a_{n,\pi(n)}
$$
The sum ranges over all permutations $\pi\in S_{n+1}$.

[The permanent cannot be computed quickly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-completeness_of_01-permanent). However, since $+1\equiv -1\pmod 2$, the determinant and the permanent are the same modulo $2$, and the determinant can be computed in $O(n^3)$ time. In conclusion, to solve your problem, just compute the determinant of $A$, and the result will have the same parity as the coefficient of $x_0\cdots x_n$.

---

To do this in a generating function sort of way, you can compute
$$
\frac{\partial^{n+1}f}{\partial x_0\partial x_1\cdots \partial x_n}
$$
where $f(x)=\prod_i \sum_j a_{i,j}x_j$, and then set $x_0=x_1=\dots=x_n=0$ in the resulting expression. However, this method would still require $O(n!)$ time, since applying $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ requires using the product rule, which causes the number of summands to expand exponentially.

Comment: Thank you Mike! Excellent explanation!